# ifstream reading multiple data types from same line BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ifstream

I'm trying to read in multiple element types from a text file.
Here's an example input:

```
push 0
push 1
push 3
push 5
add
push 3
```

The code below work until the last line, then I get a BAD_ACCESS error after trying anything after it reads in a line without 'b'. Any suggestions?

```
ifstream infile("example.txt");

while (!infile.eof())
{
    infile >> a >> b;

    if (a == "push")
        push(b);

    if (a == "add")
    {
        add();
    }
    if (a == "subtract")
    {
        int y = subtract();
        cout << y << endl;
    }

    if (a == "multiply")
    {
        int y = multiply();
        cout << y << endl;
    }

    if (a == "divide")
    {
        int y = divide();
        cout << y << endl;
    }

    if (a == "pop")
    {
        cout << b;
        b = NULL;

    }
    cout << a << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your problem exists because you always read in two tokens, but you have an odd number of tokens since the "add" line only takes one.  You can change your input so each line is always two tokens, or read in one token at a time.

Comment: I can't change the input. How would I read one at a time without skipping lines?